How to pass a peer/sub-proxy from ACL script back to Squid?
Let's say, I have a python script which handles ACL:
#squid.conf
# [............]

# sub-proxies/peers
cache_peer 01.01.01.99 parent 30024 0 no-query no-digest name=peer1
cache_peer 01.01.02.99 parent 30024 0 no-query no-digest name=peer2
cache_peer 01.01.03.99 parent 30024 0 no-query no-digest name=peer3
cache_peer 01.01.04.99 parent 30024 0 no-query no-digest name=peer4


external_acl_type my_acl_helper ttl=30 %LOGIN ./my_acl_helper.py
acl session_acl external my_acl_helper

# [............]

In my_acl_helper.py there's some tricky logic of selecting a peer to be used for a request.
Once a proxy has been chosen in my_acl_helper.py, how would it report it back to Squid? In what format? As far as I've found out, only OK and ERR are supported. Whereas I need to pass a proxy, IP:port or an alias of it, as well. How would I or what would be a workaround?
